# Is there any commonality between Math induction and Logic induction?

Tags: logic, induction

Logic induction is reasoning by probability.

Math induction seems to be related to just Natural numbers and used to prove a statement for every natural number.

From these definitions there is no relationship between the two concepts or are there details within each of these concepts that are common ?

Update :

Ref : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F8IDj6I-tM&list=PLS8vfA_ckeuZ9UjAHhA1q-ROZGuE_h21V&index=3 at time 4:42

screenshot :

[image]

Comment: "Logic induction is reasoning by probability". Definitions and references?

Comment: @GitGud please see update

Comment: @GitGud The induction mentioned in the video is certainly not reasoning by *mathematical* probability, although I suppose Bayesian thinking could aid such induction. He's really talking about [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning) in the philosophical sense of arguing from special cases to the general.

Comment: And to the OP: No, the two concepts are quite different. Apart from the name there is a certain superficial similarity, but that seems to dissipate once you look closer.

Comment: You can see also [Inductive Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-inductive/).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I worked through examples in my answer and found that there does exist something in common.  I can't use mathematical induction without a base case, now can?  And can I use logic induction without a base case?  It looks to me like the concepts definitely have something in common.  Can you persuade me by thorough examples that they have NOTHING in common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the viewpoint of modern logic, no, they are just different things.  There is an historical connection though.  Historically, for some logicians, "induction" was inference from special cases to a general rule.  This is related to the definition you found, in that some logicians would say that special cases can make the general rule probable though they can not prove it deductively.

On the other hand, mathematical induction was so-called by Augustus de Morgan because he saw it as getting a general rule from successive cases.  See Gerald Edgar's answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24102/historically-first-uses-of-mathematical-induction

Contrary to what a lot of people think, mathematical induction is not an inference made from infinitely many cases.  It is not the idea that given $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ and $P(2)$ and so on through $P(n)$ for every specific natural number $n$, you can infer "for all natural numbers $n$, $P(n)$.'' In fact that principle is called Hilbert's Omega rule, and it does not hold in  Peano Arithmetic, or in ZFC, or indeed in any consistent recursively axiomatized theory.

But mathematical induction does hold in those theories.  It is a principle about what you can infer given two things: $P(0)$ and a proof for an indeterminate $n$ that "If $P(n)$ then $P(n+1)$.''  Not infinitely many different concrete numbers $n$, but a single indeterminate $n$, logically speaking a variable.  Peano Arithmetic and ZFC both let you infer "for all natural numbers $n$, $P(n)$'' from those.

To see this intuitively think of  G\"odel's second incompleteness theorem.  If PA is consistent, then for every concretely given natural number $n$ it has to prove "$n$ does not code a proof in PA of $0=1$.''  That is because each concrete case can be checked concretely (given enough time).  But the different cases have little to do with each other.  The assumption that $n$ does not code such a proof gives you no leg up on showing that $n+1$ does not.  You cannot organize the reasoning to work for an actually indeterminate $n$.  And so PA does not prove "for all $n$, $n$ does not code a proof of $0=1$.

To clarify the usage: "mathematical induction" is normally understood the way the OP uses it.  It is reasoning  on the natural numbers, by proving a base case of $n=0$ and then an induction step where you assume the conclusion for an indeterminate $n$ and prove it for $n+1$. It is taken as an axiom scheme in formalized arithmetic, and (in one form or another, depending on details) is a part of the definition of the set of natural numbers in set theory.

This is far from the only kind of induction used in mathematics.  Other prominent notions of induction are transfinite induction used on transfinite ordinals in set theory, epsilon-induction used in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory, and Noetherian induction used on ideals of Noetherian rings (or on open subsets of Noetherian spaces).  There is even a general theory of "well-founded relations," which in brief means relations that support a generalized concept of inductive proof.  These are well explained many places on line.

None of those senses of induction involve any notion of probability.  Nor can standard uses of "inductive reasoning" in probability be justified by somehow reducing them to these.  But there is the historical link described above.

Comment: What is the "viewpoint of modern logic"?   Where is the philosophical tome which thoroughly explains what this "viewpoint" is?  I mean, I've provided an answer which indicates *something* in common between the two.  Am I now an "ancient philosopher"?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I too indicate something they have in common.  In case you are concerned, that is not my downvote on your answer.  If you want, you could post a question about "modern logic.".

Comment: I think it's important to distinguish between mathematical logic and the kinds of logics which are used in other subjects. Mathematical induction is very tightly axiomatized and explained within the mathematical logic framework, including ZF set theory within that fairly rigorous framework. The kind of induction you read about in philosophy-oriented textbooks is much more woolly. There are several logic textbooks which include both the informal logics and the mathematical logic frameworks. My list of 50 logic textbooks is [here](http://www.geometry.org/tex/conc/logicbooks.html).

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I posted it a question about modern logic here.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373040/what-is-the-viewpoint-of-modern-logic  Apparently, that's too broad of a question around here.

Comment: @AlanU.Kennington Is the omission of Frege's "Concept Script"  in your list deliberate?  Also, there's Jan Lukasiewicz's Elements of Mathematical Logic, and Arthur Prior's Formal Logic.  Prior's book has an appendix with several axiom sets. Nicod's proof *for the completeness* of his axiom was incorrect. For more details see this paper: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1093958259  C. A. Meredith's paper didn't establish that a single axiom could suffice for propositional calculus. If I recall correctly, Tarski did so. See the papers in the volume "Polish Logic" for details.

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood Many thanks for that. I'll look into the additional info you've given me. Concerning the omissions in my book list, that's because I only list works which I have myself in my hands as physical printed books, or which are available in PDF free online from legal sources. I don't have access to a university library. I needed all of these books and papers for my own book that I'm writing. I wasn't trying to create a comprehensive summary of the entire logic literature. From memory, I think some of Frege's works are available in print at very high price. I avoid excessive prices!

Comment: @Doug Spoonwood Concerning the mark-down of your "modern logic" question, I actually prefer the questions about meaning and history and "broad" principles and so forth. Sometimes I get the impression that this is a "homework help" web site, which is really the job of a tutor or fellow students (or the teacher). It's the broader questions which are difficult to get into in the rough and tumble of undergraduate life. There's a "history of science and math" SE site, but it's not teeming with activity and excitement right now!

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, you could regard the two kinds of induction as complementary. Keep in mind that the human brain works by pattern recognition. It's a big pattern recognition machine. When you do induction from observations in nature, you are inferring a pattern from what you see in the real world. In this case, the neural network (i.e. brain) sees many examples and forms a pattern which seems to fit what it seen.

By contrast, in mathematical induction, you have a pattern which is a formula or rule which applies to an infinite sequence of cases. Then your task is to prove logically that the pattern is in fact valid.

Thus in the first case, you are inferring the pattern from repeated observations. In the second case, you are verifying absolutely that the formula is always correct.

Trivial example. You might notice that when you multiply an integer by 5, it ends in 5 if the number was odd or 0 when the number was even. This hunch could then be verified by mathematical induction.

Perhaps I could add that the same issue occurs with the word "inference". It is sometimes used in the sense of statistical inference, making a probabilistic guess that something is true with some confidence level. The word "inference" is also often used in mathematical logic books to mean logical deduction which is water-tight with total certainty.

Answer (score -3):

I'll first indicate that mathematical induction does appear outside the natural numbers.  For instance, common proofs of the deduction meta-theorem use mathematical induction.

Both mathematical induction and logic induction start with at least one thing satisfying a property.

To use the example of the video, if I reason using logic induction one might argue as follows:

Base cases: The Sun rose the day before yesterday, yesterday, and today.

Therefore, the Sun will rise tommorow.

If I use mathematical induction I might write a proof like the following:

Base Cases: 0 is a natural number.  And 0 = 0.  1 = 0, and 2 = 0.

Induction case: The induction step involves us proving that for a natural number called "num", if num = 0, then (num + 1) = 0.  So, let's assume that num = 0.  Since num = 0, (num + 1) = (0 + 1).  And (0 + 1) = 1.  Thus, (num + 1) = 1.  By the second base case above, that is 1 = 0, it follows that (num + 1) = 0.  Consequently, we've proved that the inductive schema holds.

Therefore, the successor of any natural number equals 0.  Since every natural number equals the successor of some other natural number, all natural numbers equal 0.

Of course that isn't correct, because it isn't the case that 1 = 0 or 2 = 0.  But I'll also point out that the Sun doesn't rise.. the Earth turns inward towards the Sun!